# Python count number of rows in CSV and pass each row to variable

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I have a .csv that looks like this:

```
Name    Gender     DOB      Status
A       M          12/13/79  Expired
B       F          10/25/75  Undocumented
```

I am trying to update each record to a website using selenium.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rec = pd.read_table('oldclients.csv', sep=',')

count_row = people.shape[0]
print (count_row)
s=people.loc[0].tolist()
```

So far i have been able to use `s[1] s[2]` to pass variables to selenium to update the web page but I only got it working for one row.

My logic is

```
Count Number of rows in csv
Foreach Row in csv -> pass values
Selenium-> Insert said values in webpage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem multiple ways:

### 1. Manually looping through rows

If this is what you want to do, you want to use [`pd.DataFrame.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

```
for row in people.iterrows():
    #your code here
```

### 2. Applying a function to the DataFrame

This is what I would recommend because it feels more native to pandas.

```
def func(row):
    #This function takes in a row and does something with Selenium
    #and does not return anything.
people.apply(func, axis=1) 
#^This applies the function to each row but does not actually change people.
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code iterates through dataframe and provides values

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    name = row.Name
    gender = row.Gender
    ...
    do something with the values and send to selenium
    ...
```